# How to setup a layer that takes grayscale image and ouputs ARGB making one of the grayscale color transparent?

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-segmentation, coreml, mlmodel

I started with DeepLabV3+ mlmodel that outputs 2D Multiarray (Segmented). Successfully added a layer that takes this as an input and outputs GRAYSCALE image.

Now, I would like to take this GrayScale image as input and output ARGB, in which I would like to make either one of the color transparent.

How to setup such a layer?

My python code for this:

```
import coremltools
import coremltools.proto.FeatureTypes_pb2 as ft

coreml_model = coremltools.models.MLModel('DeepLabKP.mlmodel')
spec = coreml_model.get_spec()
spec_layers = getattr(spec,spec.WhichOneof("Type")).layers


# find the current output layer and save it for later reference
last_layer = spec_layers[-1]
 
# add the post-processing layer
new_layer = spec_layers.add()
new_layer.name = 'image_gray_to_RGB'
 
# Configure it as an activation layer
new_layer.activation.linear.alpha = 255
new_layer.activation.linear.beta = 0
 
# Use the original model's output as input to this layer
new_layer.input.append(last_layer.output[0])
 
# Name the output for later reference when saving the model
new_layer.output.append('image_gray_to_RGB')
 
# Find the original model's output description
output_description = next(x for x in spec.description.output if x.name==last_layer.output[0])
 
# Update it to use the new layer as output
output_description.name = new_layer.name


# Function to mark the layer as output
# https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/81571#241998
def convert_grayscale_image_to_RGB(spec, feature_name, is_bgr=False): 
    """ 
    Convert an output multiarray to be represented as an image 
    This will modify the Model_pb spec passed in. 
    Example: 
        model = coremltools.models.MLModel('MyNeuralNetwork.mlmodel') 
        spec = model.get_spec() 
        convert_multiarray_output_to_image(spec,'imageOutput',is_bgr=False) 
        newModel = coremltools.models.MLModel(spec) 
        newModel.save('MyNeuralNetworkWithImageOutput.mlmodel') 
    Parameters 
    ---------- 
    spec: Model_pb 
        The specification containing the output feature to convert 
    feature_name: str 
        The name of the multiarray output feature you want to convert 
    is_bgr: boolean 
        If multiarray has 3 channels, set to True for RGB pixel order or false for BGR 
    """
    for output in spec.description.output: 
        if output.name != feature_name: 
            continue
        if output.type.WhichOneof('Type') != 'imageType': 
            raise ValueError("%s is not a image type" % output.name)
        output.type.imageType.colorSpace = ft.ImageFeatureType.ColorSpace.Value('RGB')
 
# Mark the new layer as image
convert_grayscale_image_to_RGB(spec, output_description.name, is_bgr=False)

updated_model = coremltools.models.MLModel(spec)
 
updated_model.author = 'Saran'
updated_model.license = 'MIT'
updated_model.short_description = 'Inherits DeepLab V3+ and adds a layer to turn scores into an image'
updated_model.input_description['image'] = 'Input Image'
updated_model.output_description[output_description.name] = 'RGB Image'
 
model_file_name = 'DeepLabKP-G2R.mlmodel'
updated_model.save(model_file_name)
```

While model successfully saves without any error, prediction errors as below

```
result = model.predict({'image': img})
  File "/Users/saran/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/coremltools/models/model.py", line 336, in predict
    return self.__proxy__.predict(data, useCPUOnly)
RuntimeError: {
    NSLocalizedDescription = "Failed to convert output image_gray_to_RGB to image";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=com.apple.CoreML Code=0 \"Invalid array shape (\n    1,\n    513,\n    513\n) for converting to gray image\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid array shape (\n    1,\n    513,\n    513\n) for converting to gray image}";
}
```

I feel like it has to do with how activation is set in this layer. But couldn't find anything to try that differently.

Any help is very much appreciated.

They grayScale image that the layer I added producing

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your output has shape (1, 513, 513). The first number, 1, is the number of channels. Since this is 1, Core ML can only turn the output into a grayscale image. A color image needs 3 channels, or a shape of (3, 513, 513).

Since this is DeepLab, I'm assuming your grayscale image doesn't really have "colors" in it but the index of the class (in other words, you've taken the ARGMAX over the predictions). The easiest way, in my opinion, to turn this grayscale "image" (segmentation mask, really) into a color image is to do this in Swift or in Metal.

Here is a source code example: https://github.com/hollance/SemanticSegmentationMetalDemo

Comment: Attached grayscale image output that I am getting from previous layer that I added to the above question. I am fine if I don't get original colors back. As long as I could make segmented portion transparent by turning into 3 channel, even with some default values, i will be happy. I will take that and use as mask for compositing with original image. Thanks for the link, I will take a look at that as well.